# Atualizar projeto android

Tags: android, gradle

Tenho em minhas mão um projeto de 3 anos atras e preciso colocar ele pra rodar, logo quando abri o projeto no android studio ja deu o erro padrão do gradle, mudei a linha

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0-rc2' -> classpath 'org.gradle:gradle 2.2.1'
```

Porem esta me retornando o seguinte erro:

```
Error:Could not find org.gradle:gradle 2.2.1:.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/org/gradle/gradle 2.2.1//gradle 2.2.1-.pom
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/org/gradle/gradle 2.2.1//gradle 2.2.1-.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/gradle/gradle 2.2.1//gradle 2.2.1-.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/gradle/gradle 2.2.1//gradle 2.2.1-.jar
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/gradle/gradle 2.2.1//gradle 2.2.1-.pom
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/gradle/gradle 2.2.1//gradle 2.2.1-.jar
Required by:
    :android:unspecified
```

Alguém pode me ajudar a fazer isso, sem eu ter que ficar tentando atualizar, voltar versão e baixar mil coisas até estourar minha memória, alguém que saiba exatamente o que esta acontecendo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver atualizando alinha para `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'`

Answer (score 1):

Marcius, já que você vai atualizar o app, considere usar a última versão do gradle, que é a `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'.`

Provavelmente para encontrar essa versão, você também precise alterar essa linha `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip`
dentro do arquivo

```
gradle-wrapper.properties
```